# Sync MySQL with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008-r2

My current project requires a form on my website to populate a table in a MySQL database with data a user submits via the form. This will work great but my complete goal involves getting that data into a MSSQL table.

I'm populating the MySQL table and linking to this MySQL data from MS SQL Management Studio via a linked table. I am able to connect to the MySQL database successfully.

My question is whether or not I'm going in the right direction, and further, how do I get this data sent into a MSSQL table? The project I am on involves giving my users visibility to data submitted via the web forms as soon as it is submitted.

Curious if there is any feedback that can point me in the right direction for this particular scenario? What is the best practice for a situation that requires a website to populate a MySQL database, and that data getting "copied" to a MSSQL server database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to find a soft that simulates replication or write a module for mssql yourself like adviced here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874587/replicate-microsoft-sql-to-other-databases